# MRJob determining if running inline, local, emr or hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, emr, mrjob, common-crawl

I am [building on some old code from a few years back using the commoncrawl dataset](https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-mrjob) with EMR using MRJob. The code uses the following inside MRJob subclass mapper function to determine whether running locally or on emr:

```
self.options.runner == 'emr'
```

This seems to either have never worked or no longer works, self.options.runner is not passed through to the tasks and therefore is always set to the default of `'inline'`. Question is, is there a way to determine whether the code is running locally or on emr with the current version of MRJob (v0.5.0).

Comment: Got the same error. The problem is now tracked at https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-mrjob/issues/7

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @pykler and @sebastian-nagel for posting about this, as trying to get the Common Crawl Python example working on Amazon EMR has been a headache.

In response to the solution @pykler posted, I believe there's a more idiomatic way that's [shown in this PDF](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/mrjob/latest/mrjob.pdf#section*.279):

```
class CCJob(MRJob):
  def configure_options(self):
    super(CCJob, self).configure_options()
    self.pass_through_option('--runner')
    self.pass_through_option('-r')
```

and then the rest of the code, i.e. the `if self.options.runner in ['emr', 'hadoop']` check, can be left as is and it should work on EMR by just passing the `-r emr` option as normal.

Also, there seems to be an issue when running a script on EMR that imports the `mrcc` module. I got an `ImportError` saying the module could not be found.

To get around this, you should create a new file of the code you want to run with the `from mrcc import CCJob` import replaced with the actual `mrcc.py` code. This is [shown in this fork](https://github.com/mpenkov/cc-mrjob#running-via-elastic-mapreduce) of the cc-mrjob repo.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution, but I am still searching for a builtin solution if anyone knows of it. [You can add a custom passthrough option that gets passed to your tasks](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/writing-mrjobs.html#passthrough-options), which would look like so:

```
class CCJob(MRJob):

def configure_options(self):
  super(CCJob, self).configure_options()
  self.add_passthrough_option(
   '--platform', default='local', choices=['local', 'remote'],
   help="indicate running remotely")

 def mapper(self, _, line):
   if self.options.platform == 'remote':
     pass
```

And you must pass `--platform remote` when running remotely